# ExactTarget Fuel SDK C# - Create subscriber not working

Tags: marketing-cloud, fuel-sdk, mobileconnect, subscriber

I am trying to add subscribers via FuelSDK C#.

I have added Email Demographics Data, but what is the right way add MobileConnect Demographics Data?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I am afraid that you cannot use FuelSDK you have to use the REST API, have a look at the doc: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/createContacts.htm, there is a sample of the contact creation.